# how to crop bitmap using com.android.camera.action.CROP

Tags: android, image, bitmap, crop, android-image

I read many example using com.android.camera.action.CROP, but they all say to crop image from galery or camera.. Anyone can tell me how to crop Bitmap using com.android.camera.CROP??
i had tried many ways, but still failed..
i had try to save the bitmap to file, and create a uri variabel from that file and use the uri variable as data at com.android.camera.action.CROP... but it still failed... T.T

this is my code

```
public class CobaSaveImageActivity extends Activity {
public ImageView tampilan;
public static Bitmap bmp;
public Uri mImageCaptureUri;
int i = 1;
File f;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tampilan = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    //bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/bluetooth/enigma.bmp");
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/enigma.jpg");
    tampilan.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
public void save (View v){
    f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/image/save"+i+".jpg");
    if (f.exists()) fileCheker(f);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        BufferedOutputStream bit = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);           
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bit);
        bit.flush();
        bit.close();
        //bmp.recycle();
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse
                ("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        Toast.makeText(this, "save complete to "+f.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        doCrop();

     } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void fileCheker(File in){
    i++;
    f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/image/save"+i+".jpg");
    if (f.exists()) fileCheker(f);
}

public static Bitmap grayscale (Bitmap bmp){
    int height, width;
    int pixel, A, R, G, B;
    width = bmp.getWidth();
    height = bmp.getHeight();

    Bitmap bmpGray = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

    for (int i =0;i<width;++i){
        for(int j=0;j<height;++j){
                pixel = bmp.getPixel(i,j);
                A = Color.alpha(pixel);
                R = Color.red(pixel);
                G = Color.green(pixel);
                B = Color.blue(pixel);
                R = G = B = (int)((R+G+B)/3);
                bmpGray.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
        }
    }
    return bmpGray;
}

public void gray(View v){
    new backtask().execute();
    //bmp = grayscale(bmp); tampilan.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    //
}


public class backtask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    //Bitmap temp;
    ProgressDialog prog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        prog = ProgressDialog.show(CobaSaveImageActivity.this, "", "Progress...",true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bmp = grayscale(bmp);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);    
        prog.dismiss();
        tampilan.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}

private void doCrop() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
    //intent.putExtra("crop", true);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

}   

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

    switch (requestCode){
    case 1 :
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        if (extras != null){
            Bitmap crop = extras.getParcelable("data");
            tampilan.setImageBitmap(crop);
        }
    break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

That Intent is not part of the public Android API and is not guaranteed to be implemented by any device manufacturers.  It was common to find on Android 1.x and early 2.x devices, but has since fallen off.

You are better off using a method like `Bitmap.createBitmap()` or `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` to create a resized or cropped version of your original image.

Comment: Right, this has never been public. If you really want to use it in your app, your best bet is to copy the code in the app and modify as necessary. There are only a few classes and they can be used with minor modifications.